# Custom colors in Icon editor (VS 2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have one 24 bit icon in c++. I made this icon with some colors that VS 2015 offers. However, I realize that this 24 bit color struct is the same as RGB.

I wonder if there's any method to define custom colors instead of using default ones.
I've looked for some menu in VS 2015 that allows coder to define some colors, but I haven't found it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you activate/enter the icon editor in Visual Studio, you should see a "Colors" tool window, which will display an array of the 'default' (VS-provided) colours.

You can define your own colour by double-clicking on the small, square box for any of the shown colours.